# How to access postgres array index using peewee?

Tags: python, postgresql, peewee

**SQL QUERY :**
`SELECT "t1"."list"[(SELECT idx("t1"."indexList", 27) FROM "Books" AS "t1" WHERE ("t1"."id" = 60490))] FROM "Books" AS "t1" WHERE ("t1"."id" = 60490);`

I have tried this thing

`t.select(t.list.__getitem__(t.select(fn.idx(t.indexList, id).where(t.id == book_id)) - 1)).where(t.id == book_id)`

**It showing error :**

`TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'Function'`

How can I get the array index element

**First I have to get the index number then getItem from the array**

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to do this with a CTE, if that's acceptable to you. I don't quite understand what you're trying to do with your query, but here's a simple example where an index is stored in one column, and we select from the array based on that index:

```
class Reg(Model):
    key = CharField(unique=True)
    idx = IntegerField()
    values = ArrayField(CharField)
    class Meta:
        database = db

db.create_tables([Reg])

r1 = Reg.create(key='k1', idx=2, values=['i0', 'i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4', 'i5'])
r2 = Reg.create(key='k2', idx=3, values=['j0', 'j1', 'j2', 'j3', 'j4', 'j5'])

RA = Reg.alias()
cte = RA.select(RA.key, RA.idx).cte('idxq')
query = (Reg
         .select(Reg.key, Reg.values[cte.c.idx].alias('item'))
         .join(cte, on=(Reg.key == cte.c.key))
         .with_cte(cte))

for row in query:
    print(row.key, row.item)
```

This prints (pg uses 1-based indexes on arrays):

```
k1 i1
k2 j2
```